# Avoid constructor mapping fields

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper 6.2.2 with .NET Core 2.0 and its default dependency injection mechanism to map between models and DTOs. 
I need DI in my AutoMapper configs because I have to perform an `AfterMap<Action>` that needs some injected components.

The thing is, for some models that have constructors which parameters match some source member, when I enable DI for AutoMapper (add `services.AddAutoMapper()`), these constructors are by default called and fed with data, that then breaks my operations with EF.

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RoleInUser> RoleInUsers { get; } = new List<RoleInUser>();

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; }

    public User()
    {
        Roles = new JoinCollectionFacade<Role, User, RoleInUser>(this, RoleInUsers);
    }

    public User(string name, string email, ICollection<Role> roles) : this()
    {
        Roles.AddRange(roles);
    }

}

public class UserProfile : Profile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<UserDTO, User>()
            .ForMember(entity => entity.Roles, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .AfterMap<SomeAction>();
    }
}
```

In the previous snippet, `User(name, email, roles)` gets called with the list of roles.

My mapper configuration is the following (note the `DisableConstructorMapping()` option)

```
    protected override MapperConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();

            // Add all profiles in current assembly
            cfg.AddProfiles(Assemblies);
        });

        return config;
    }
```

And my `Startup` where everything is set up:

```
        var mapperProvider = new MapperProvider();
        services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(mapperProvider.GetMapper());
        services.AddAutoMapper(mapperProvider.Assemblies);
```

Modifying the profile to configure which ctor to use with `ConstructUsing`

```
    public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<UserDTO, User>()
            .ForMember(entity => entity.Roles, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ConstructUsing(src => new User())
            .AfterMap<SomeAction>();
    }
```

It works as expected, but this forces me to include this boilerplate statement in every Map configuration,
and the model is quite big.

Without dependency injection (this need arosed recently), it worked smoothly with the first snippet (no need for `ConstructUsing`).

I've searched for this scenario but haven't found anything. Is adding `ConstructUsing` to every Map the way to go? Is there any better option? Or maybe I'm doing something
completely wrong...

Comment: You need DisableConstructorMapping().

Comment: I already have it, and it makes no difference. I'll include this detail in the question

Comment: You're doing it wrong. AddAutoMapper does things for you, you don't have to register anything by hand.

Comment: What am I registering by hand? I have `AddAutoMapper` in the Startup. And, after I added that line to enable dependency injection, I started having this mapping to ctor field issue.

Comment: You only need AddAutomapper See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I've tried removing the `AddSingleton` but the issue remains the same. By the way, the two sentences are there because I followed Jimmy Bogard's post on integrating AutoMapper with Asp.NET Core DI (https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/07/20/integrating-automapper-with-asp-net-core-di/)

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: It took me a while to prepare a gist... here it is, thanks in advance! [see gist](https://gist.github.com/keycad/d71ed0dd96b148a74bb1e20d6e656578)

Comment: The code works without the DI stuff. That's because you're not using it as intended. Remove AddAutomapper, you're already doing things by hand. Or remove the MapperConfiguration and move the configuration in a profile.

Comment: [Example](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityCore/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AddAutoMapper&type=).

Comment: I tried to keep it simple, but in my real code, which is a .NET Core 2.0 Web API, I'm using DI and the profiles (see the code in my question), and after adding AddAutoMapper (which I need for DI in the AfterMap action) it started failing . Maybe I'm not explaining myself very well, this [gist with webApi](https://gist.github.com/keycad/4a8dda3ff791894d38dcf9fc51b3d536) and using .NET Core DI container is closer to my real code

Comment: Yes, but it has the exact same problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, i can see in my gist that I can remove AddAutoMapper as you say. But although it seems to be the same as my real code, if I remove it from my real code, it can't inject the injected service in the AfterMapAction (it complains about the lack of a parameterless constructor...). I'll continue investigating. Thanks again

Comment: I got to try again and nope, my last gist fails. Without AddAutoMapper: it can't inject the injected service in AfterMapAction. With it: it calls the wrong User ctor, with roles param. I've also uploaded it to [github](https://github.com/keycad/AutoMapperDI/blob/master/AutoMapperGistApi_Posted/Startup.cs)

Comment: You need the AddAutoMapper overload that allows extra configurations.

Answer (score 1):

One year later and I encountered this with AutoMapper 8.0.0. If anyone is still following this, there're 2 ways:

1. Add `ConstructUsing` to your every `CreateMap<Src, Des>`.
2. Modify/Add to your `ConfigureServices` this line: `services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.DisableConstructorMapping());`

But you have to create a blank constructor in every class needed mapping.