# Global/Shared mapping configuration: custom mappings & ignores

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I'm working with .NET Core 2.0 and AutoMapper 6.2.2.

I'm using `AssertConfigurationIsValid` to make sure my mappings are correct and I have defined a number of `AutoMapper.Profile` which share some mapping rules:

- Since I'm mapping between model entities and DTOs, I want field `id`
  to be ignored in every `entity <=> DTO` mapping.
- I also want `AutoGeneratedAppid` to be mapped to `AppId` in every
  `entity <=> DTO` mapping.

For instance:

```
public class Role
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string AutoGeneratedAppId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RoleDTO
{
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class RoleProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public RoleProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Role, RoleDTO>();

        CreateMap<RoleDTO, Role>();
        //.ForMember(entity => entity.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
        //.ForMember(entity => entity.AutoGeneratedAppId, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.AppId));
    }
}
```

Since there both multiple mappings and multiple fields to be ignored/mapped in the same way in each mapping, I'm trying to found a way of avoiding having to define in every profile common rules this like:

- `.ForMember(entity => entity.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());`
- `.ForMember(entity => entity.AutoGeneratedAppId, opt => opt.MapFrom(dto => dto.AppId));`

I can't find a way to avoid a `AutoMapperConfigurationException` in `AssertConfigurationIsValid` when mapping `dto => entity` due to unmapped `id` and `AutoGeneratedAppId` properties.

My mapper configuration, with my failed trials, is the following:

```
    protected override MapperConfiguration CreateConfiguration()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();
            cfg.AddProfiles(Assemblies);

            // Global ignoring - alternative 1
            cfg.ShouldMapProperty = prop =>
                prop.Name != "Id";

            // Global ignoring - alternative 2
            cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("Id");

            // Global ignoring - alternative 3
            cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(map =>
                map.SourceMember.Name.EndsWith("Id"),
                (map, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Ignore();
                });

            // Entity.AutoGeneratedAppId => DTO.AppId
            cfg.RecognizePrefixes("AutoGenerated");
            // DTO.AppId => Entity.AutoGeneratedAppId
            cfg.RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("AutoGenerated");
        });

        return config;
    }
```

My `Startup` configuration is the following:

```
var mapperProvider = new MapperProvider();
services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(mapperProvider.GetMapper());
services.AddAutoMapper(mapperProvider.Assemblies);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need [AddGlobalIgnore](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AddGlobalIgnore&type=) and [ForAllMaps](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ForAllMaps&type=) with ForMember. You also need to remove AddAutomapper or move your configuration inside a profile.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790180/avoid-constructor-mapping-fields.

Comment: I've just tried with `cfg.AddGlobalIgnore("Id");` + `cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, map) => map.ForMember("Id", prop => prop.Ignore()));` and removing `AddAutoMapper` and I'm still getting the exception of unmapped prop.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Real codebase I'm working on makes it difficult to place it in a gist, but no global configuration seems to work in my setup, no matter what it is.

I've managed to achieve global ignores and dealing with prefixes by using a common profile and make he rest inherit from it, so thanks for that idea.